# VB Folder: Access Denied (with admin rights)

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application

i'm using VB.NET language on windows 10 with VS 2015

I'm trying to make a directory then copy a file from my app's resources folder to that directory

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SubFolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "Main Folder\Sub Folder")

    Directory.CreateDirectory(SubFolderPath)

    'Error: access denied to "C:\Program Files\Main Folder\Sub Folder"
    File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath, My.Resources.exe1)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath, My.Resources.exe2)
    File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath, My.Resources.exe2dat)
End Sub
```

i get error as commented in the above code, (i have admin rights)

Code result: created folder "C:\Program Files\Main Folder\Sub Folder" but then access denied while copying.

i'm not knowing why access is denied... can you help me please?

Comment: This is only a guess... Have you tried setting the directories to not be read-only?

Comment: @KyleWilliamson nope.. how? when i enter folder settings (in windows explorer) "reed-only" option is selected automatically even if i remove it..

Comment: Have you tried adding a Backslash to the end of "Sub Folder"?

Comment: @Kyle the same happened

Comment: Okay. Trying to work this out with you.  Have you tried creating a directory in a different area?  Maybe MyDocuments?

Comment: @Kyle now tried... the same result but in documents this time... is the code correct?

Comment: what type is the `My.Resources.exe1` variable?

Comment: @Kyle if i understood then: `exe1` is an executable file exe, `exe2` is exe too, but `exe2dat` is a `.dat` file

Comment: Are you trying to copy files?  According to MSDN the second parameter should be of type Byte().

Comment: @Kyle if not `exe` type is byte then is there a way to make it of byte type?, please simplify because i don't know much in vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you specify a directory name instead of a file name as the first argument of the `File.WriteAllBytes` methods:

> ```
> File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath, My.Resources.exe1)`
> ```

Do something like this to correct it:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath & "\exe1.exe", My.Resources.exe1)
File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath & "\exe2.exe", My.Resources.exe2)
File.WriteAllBytes(SubFolderPath & "\exe2dat.dat", My.Resources.exe2dat)
```

And it's not a problem with `Byte()`. Whenever you import a binary exe to your resources, it is stored as a `Byte()`. You need not worry about that.

Comment: I have already tested this before using the last code, ill test again.. maybe I missed something in the code

Comment: @NHK it is the problem mentioned in my answer which causes the error. Try with admin privilleges : `File.WriteAllBytes("D:\", My.Resources.exe1)`. Even this will throw the 'Access Denied' exception. But try "D:\exe1" and it works like a charm

Comment: worked finally, probably I was missing the \ character. I used the code that u posted above